# How can I Get the details from Root-CA-Cert certificate (x509) chain using c#?

Tags: c#, x509

Let's say I have three certificates (in Base64 format)

```
Root
 |
 --- CA
     |
     --- Cert (client/signing/whatever)
```

How can I Get the data from certificate chain in C#? (All those three certs may be in my computer cert store)

How can I Get the details from Root-CA-Cert certificate (x509) chain using c#?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> How can I Get the data from certificate chain in C#? 
> ...
> How can I Get the details from Root-CA-Cert certificate (x509) chain using c#?
> ```

You can use .Net's [X509Certificate Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It has methods like `GetCertHash`, `GetPublicKey`, `GetSerialNumber`, `GetEffectiveDateString` (i.e., notBefore), `GetExpirationDateString` (i.e., `notAfter`); and properties like `Issuer` and `Subject`.

For the purposes of displaying information, there is no difference between a root certificate, intermediate certificate or server certificate. A CA is just self signed (some hand waiving), which means the `Issuer` and `Subject` are the same. You can also root your trust in an intermediate, and that would not be self signed. With intermediate and server certificates, the `Issuer` and `Subject` will likely be different.

Also, this is probably a better visualization:

```
Root or CA
 |
 --- Intermediate
     |
     --- Server (client/signing/whatever)
```